# How to get Latitude and Longitude information from picture

Tags: java, android, image, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How to get latitude and longitude information from picture store in device or SD Card?

Comment: while the picture is being taken or after?

Comment: I want to get information of longitude and latitude from pictures store in device or SD Card.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found very simple solution for this question....So I posted it here to help my friends who have problem like me to get Geo location from Picture.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(null != bundle)
{
    String filepath = bundle.getString(FILE_PATH_KEY);

    try 
    {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("Date & Time: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Flash: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n");
        builder.append("Focal Length: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("GPS Datestamp: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Latitude: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Latitude Ref: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Longitude: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Longitude Ref: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Processing Method: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Timestamp: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Image Length: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH) + "\n");
        builder.append("Image Width: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Camera Make: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera Model: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera Orientation: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera White Balance: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE) + "\n");         

        builder = null;
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

We can get all the Exif tag information from picture in one builder string.

Comment: can you please tell me what is getExifTag?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ExifInterface class to read various EXIF metadata from JPEGs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Comment: I love it when people take your advice, then post it as their own answer.

Comment: @Nate well, we can also debate as if Cody's answer is a "link only" answer or not. Mohit answer at least shows the code to get Latitude and Longitude.